# Samsung S7 Edge Google Sign In result.isSuccess() always false

Tags: android, google-signin, galaxy

As the title goes, currently I'm facing problem with Samsung S7 Edge, which my client said he can't log in. The login use Google Sign In. First I thought it is because of Android M, but it's not (after tested the app using Honor 5C). Other phone (Android J, K and L) have no problem.

Since I don't have one to use for testing and see the cause in logcat, is it because of the phone or the code?

in OnCreate:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

When user click Log In button:

```
private void registerWithGoogle() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //If signin
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            //Calling a new function to handle signin
            handleRegisterResult(result);
        }
    }

private void handleRegisterResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //Getting google account
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        String name = acct.getDisplayName();
        name = name.replace(" ", "%20");

        String phoneNo = editTextPhoneNo.getText().toString();
        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("+", "%2B");

        String email = acct.getEmail();

        String code = textViewCode.getText().toString();
        code = code.replace("+", "%2B");

        registerUser(name,
                phoneNo,
                email,
                code);

    } else {
        String msg = "Error when register";
        snackBar(msg);
    }
}
```

He always got `Error when register`. Or is there any other cause of problem?